# Leetcode problem 14. Longest Common Prefix (Python)

Tags: python

I tried to solve the problem (you can read description here: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/) And the following is code I came up with.
It gives `prefix` value of the first string in `strs` list and compares prefix with every string from the list, popping all characters that are not equal.

```py
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        prefix = strs[0][0]
        for i in range(len(strs)):
            for j in range(len(prefix)):
                if strs[i][j] != prefix[j]:
                    prefix.pop(prefix[j])
        return prefix
```

But this code fails in the very first testcase where `strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]`
Expected output is `"fl"`, while my code returns just `"f"`
I am struggling to find what is going wrong in my solution. Maybe you can help?

Comment: from initially prefix only contains value only alphabet `f` i think you wanted `prefix=strs[0]`

Comment: also if you run after this string index out of range bcoz you assuming all words are of same length..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the characters in parallel with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
strs = ["flower", "flow", "flight"]

n = 0
for chars in zip(*strs):
    if len(set(chars)) > 1:
        break
    n += 1

# length
print(n) # 2

# prefix
print(strs[0][:n]) # fl
```

Similar approach as a one-liner using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile

prefix = ''.join([x[0] for x in takewhile(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 1, zip(*strs))])
```

Comment: ```strs[0][:n]``` means all characters before nth from ```strs[0]```? how is this instrument called?

Comment: Yes, this is called *slicing*.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could try to use the lib in **os** - *commonprefix:*
(it's available since Python 3.5+)

```py
def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        return os.path.commonprefix(strs)


strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
print(longestCommonPrefix(strs))
```